# While running test cases related to jest in angular framework throwing error TypeError: clone is not a function

Tags: typescript

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA2N9.png)

I tried to mock the /graceful-fs.js node module.
I try to mock the mode modules but still not working
the angular version is 12 and the jest version is 27 and I am trying to do unit test.
From graceful-fs it is showing typeerror: clone is not a function.